# Update persistent object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to update an Object. I fetch it. The object is a Persistent Object. Now.. If I change any properties, because is a persistent (not detached) object, any varations is immediately saved? I need to call a function? Or when session is flushed, the modification are stored?

Comment: I dont understand what is the problem ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a persistent object, the changes will be saved when the session is flushed.

Comment: Ok. This mean that when my struts2 action modify the properties, before to return SUCCESS, the session must to be flushed. But, if the session is managed by a spring bean, how tell to flush?

Comment: @luigi, the session flushes automatically before it closes.  If you have configured your session to be open for the entire request, it will flush after your action returns.  You can flush explicitly with session.flush(), once you get the session.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-modifying

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Chris's answer, and the followup question "how do I configure the session to close after the request": the traditional way to do this is to wrap the relevant servlets (assuming this is a web application) in a Filter that opens a session and associates it with the current thread, calls doFilter, and then either commits or rolls back the transaction based on whether an error occured.  This is known as the "Open Session in View" pattern.